# Variables from one table display along side another in the view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Hi there I was looking for a way to  select certain fields from the different database tables and output it into one table in the view.This is the code I have so far although it is only able to retrieve information from the patients table. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

model

```
namespace ChampPMS.Models
{
    public class Patient
    {
        public int PatientID { get; set; }     
        public string HouseChartNo { get; set; }    
        public string ClinicChartNo { get; set; }  
        public string Title { get; set; }  
        public string FirstName { get; set; }   
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

Dont think this is right.

```
       //Other Table variables
        public Admission  ExpectedDate { get; set; } ------->from bed 
        public Beds Bed { get; set; }  ------->from admissions
```

}

```
    public class Beds
    {

        public int BedID { get; set; }
        public int RoomID { get; set; }
        public string Bed { get; set; }         
    }

    public class Admission
    {
        public int AdmissionID { get; set; }
        public int PatientID { get; set; }           
        public DateTime ExpectedDate { get; set; }       
        public int BedID { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }        
    }

        public PatientDBContext()
        : base("PatientsDBContext")//connection string
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Admission> Admission { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Beds> Beds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Patient> Patient { get; set; }
}
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<ChampPMS.Models.Patient>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
</p>
<table class="table  table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered ">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HouseChartNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClinicChartNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bed)----->from bed table
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpectedDate)----->from admission table
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HouseChartNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClinicChartNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SurName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bed)------->from bed table
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpectedDate) ----->from admission table
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PatientID }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-info" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PatientID }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-primary" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PatientID }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ChampPMS.Models;

namespace ChampPMS.Controllers
{
    public class PatientsController : Controller
    {
        private PatientDBContext db = new PatientDBContext();

        // GET: Patients
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Patient.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Patients/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Patient patient = db.Patient.Find(id);
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(patient);
        }

        // GET: Patients/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Patients/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PatientID,HouseChartNo,ClinicChartNo,Title,FirstName,SurName,DOB,HouseName,Street,Town,County,Telephone,Mobile,Gender,Occupation,Marital,TaxNumber,GMSnumber,DPSnumber,ReligionID,Status,HashCode")] Patient patient)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Patient.Add(patient);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(patient);
        }

        // GET: Patients/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Patient patient = db.Patient.Find(id);
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(patient);
        }

        // POST: Patients/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PatientID,HouseChartNo,ClinicChartNo,Title,FirstName,SurName,DOB,HouseName,Street,Town,County,Telephone,Mobile,Gender,Occupation,Marital,TaxNumber,GMSnumber,DPSnumber,ReligionID,Status,HashCode")] Patient patient)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(patient);
        }

        // GET: Patients/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Patient patient = db.Patient.Find(id);
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(patient);
        }

        // POST: Patients/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Patient patient = db.Patient.Find(id);
            db.Patient.Remove(patient);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code you are using to get the data from the db

Answer (score 0):

Rather than return the data directly from the database to the View you should create a View-Model in the controller action.

This ViewModel would contain all of the information that you need to display.

Using a ViewModel ensures that only the data required for the View is returned. It means rendering your View is more simple and you can use data from many different sources in one single ViewModel.

Comment: Im looking into view models now just one question on that though where are view models located in controller,model or view

Comment: Generally you will construct the ViewModel within the Controller and return it to the View.

Comment: Thanks ,also though do you know how to retrieve information from multiple table and put in one in the view?